# What functions does a C++ compiler generate for you if you didn't provide

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Many default methods does a class have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044275/how-many-default-methods-does-a-class-have)

Given a class as follows:

```
class ClassA
{
    private:
      int i;
};
```

I would like to know what functions a compiler will generate for you. Here is my guess:

```
1> default constructor [ ClassA() ]
2> destructor          [ ~ClassA() ]
3> assignment operator [ ClassA& operator=(const ClassA& rhs) ]
4> copy constructor    [ ClassA(const ClassA& rhs) ]
```

Do I get it right?

Comment: Those are certainly generated. And so is operator==(const ClassA&).

Comment: @DeadMG That's why I fixed the error.